# Queue publish calls with PubNub when offline

Tags: angularjs, pubnub

I'm dabbling with using PubNub for various parts of my app.  I'm using their AngularJS library for this.

Right now, I'm just testing it for doing "analytics".  Basically, I want to track ever more a user makes in the app - buttons pressed, states navigated to, etc.  So, I track actions and publish on a channel.

It all works great - when the user is online.  However, when offline, I lose all this tracking.  I was sort of hoping that PubNub client would automatically queue all the publish requests.  It does not seem to do this.

So, I'm thinking I'll have a service to collect all publish requests and put them in a queue if the device is offline.  Once the device is back online, I'll publish any queued requests.

Is this the best approach?  Does anyone have a better suggestion?  Does PubNub already have this ability and I'm just not finding it?

Comment: Would be nice if pubnub handled this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, currently, this is the best way to achieve this.

There are different scenarios for queuing / retrying, for example -- depending on the content of the message (eg expiration/timeliness of the message), and depending on the reason (no internet, channel permissions) you may want to re-queue/retry some and not others, etc.

So if you can implement your own retry logic custom to your use case, thats ideal. We may provide more productized options on this moving forward...

geremy

Comment: Would be nice if pubnub offered this.